# gnu mipsel gcc does not seem to respect the architecture option

Tags: gcc, architecture, mips32

Compiling a test hello world C program with -march set to different values produces the same executable, e.g.,

```
$ mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc-10 -march=mips32 -static -EL /tmp/test.c -o /tmp/test_mips32
$ mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc-10 -march=mips32r2 -static -EL /tmp/test.c -o /tmp/test_mips32r2
$ mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc-10 -march=24kc -static -EL /tmp/test.c -o /tmp/test_24kc
```

and the result

```
$ file /tmp/test_mips32
/tmp/test_mips32: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=92738788137ab5f60695febf78213eb7961ef4bd, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
$ file /tmp/test_mips32r2 
/tmp/test_mips32r2: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=92738788137ab5f60695febf78213eb7961ef4bd, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
$ file /tmp/test_24kc 
/tmp/test_24kc: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=92738788137ab5f60695febf78213eb7961ef4bd, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

I have also verified that the files are byte identical.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Without actual source code it is very hard to say, but the answer might simply be that the compiler has no reason to make different choices in your situation.

Remember that all mentioned march flags share a common MIPS core, so it is not impossible to generate code that works on all three. Maybe that code is optimal in your case?